# TypeError: find() takes no argument inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

novice programmer in Python here!

I'm trying to run the code below using python 3.8.5, but I keep getting the error present in title.

Disclaimer: The code is not my original code, but it is from a YouTube video that was published in 2017. I will include its link here for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k

```
import requests
import urllib
import getpass

source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

article = soup.find('article').prettify()

# print(article)

# summary = article.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.text
# print(summary)

vid_src = article.find('iframe', class_= 'youtube-player')['src']
print(vid_src)
```

I've been playing around with this for a few days, changing my python version and downloading additional files via my terminal, but I'm still really confused.

Any/all help is appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: Show the full error with traceback and line where the error occurs when asking a question about an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the call to `.prettify()` in your code.

If you call this function, it will return a "pretty string" and you will lose your BeautifulSoup object.

```py
import requests
import urllib
import getpass

source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

article = soup.find('article')

# print(article)

# summary = article.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.text
# print(summary)

vid_src = article.find('iframe', class_= 'youtube-player')['src']
print(vid_src)
```

*Output*

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/z0gguhEmWiY?version=3&rel=1&fs=1&autohide=2&showsearch=0&showinfo=1&iv_load_policy=1&wmode=transparent
```